# You mess up a creme/pudding/etc, and it will have denser chunks in it. What do you call them?

Tags: word-request

I'm struggling to translate a word in my language that refers to a common cooking/mixing issue, but is very hard to search for translation, as we use a metaphorical word.

When you are creating some smooth creme - be it pudding, creme, glue mixture, whatever else - sometimes you mess up, and the texture will be inhomogeneous. There will be denser chunks, God forbid chunks with dry powder enclosed within them, floating in your creme, that are often really hard to get rid of. Their size can be anything, from a few millimeters to the size of a coin.

What do you call these denser chunks?

Comment: what's the word in your native language?

Comment: @Vickel *Gucsa* (Hungarian), which is also a word in traditional dialect for a kind of traditional pasta generally called [*galuska*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halu%C5%A1ky).

Comment: Sunday dinner in my childhood: Mother: do you want gravy? Me: yes please. Mother: one lump or two?

Comment: Maybe a ['glob'](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/glob) although those tend to be conglomerations of liquid, not lumpy bits of dry

Comment: "experience" acquired as part of the learning process.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Lumps.  The pudding itself is lumpy.*

For instance, this [recipe tip site](https://delishably.com/desserts/How-to-Make-Custard-to-Go-With-Puddings-and-Trifle-Easy-Recipe) observes

> Custard is a delicious accompaniment to any pudding—but has your custard ever turned out lumpy?

> What went wrong? How do you stop the lumps forming in the first place? Or if they do pop up, how do you get rid of them?

*There is apparently a recipe known as "lumpy pudding," but I have always seen it used to mean a pudding with lumps that are not desired.

Answer (score 8):

*denser chunks, with dry powder enclosed within them, floating in your creme, that are often really hard to get rid of*

those enclosures of bits of flour or similar are called

> Clumps/Lumps in the dough/pudding/etc...

Comment: enclosures of bits of flower?? Surely, you mean bits of flour.

Comment: @Lambie oops... corrected, thanks for pointing it out, happy new year!

Comment: :) To you as well. [filler]

Answer (score 3):

[Curdle](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/curdle) or [curds](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/curd) may apply.

Technically, curds are the lumps of milk proteins that form when milk goes sour or during cheese making, but less literally, curdling has connotations of lumpy spoilage/ruination that could apply to the situation you are describing.